# Any material DatePicker View (not dialog) lib support lower SDK version?

Tags: android, datepicker

I use native DatePicker on layout file, but it will not show material style for lower version (before lollipop)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<DatePicker
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/datePicker" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And i found some libs, those libs prompt a DatePickerDialog, but it is not what i want. I want the DatePicker as a widget embed on the layout

[image]

If use SDK level 19 to draw, it will look like this(not use material):
[image]

Any suggestions or recommended lib?

Comment: lower SDK version? min level ?

Comment: I am not sure, but  I think Android 4

Comment: Material Design start from lollipop, so lower version means lower than 5.0

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DateRangePicker](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2353) with minimal SDK 15. At [Android Arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/27) section dedicated to Date Pickers you can find something even more compatible for your needs.

Comment: DateRangePicker is dialog style, does any view style one?

Comment: @user3814793 I don't understand your comment at all. You can do anything you want with the library or you can use it source code to implement your own. Dialog uses certain view which you can use for your purpose.

Comment: Please look at the layout of DateRangePicker on emulator, did you tried? When you use level 19 to display on emulator, you will find out what i said

Comment: I saw it many times. I don't understand what do you want to achieve

Comment: Use level 19 on emulator and redraw, you will find out the theme would not use material